# What computer science concept deals with combining multiple conditions for efficient evaluation?

Tags: tree, conditional-statements, computer-science, boolean-logic, evaluation

I have a real world problem i'm trying to solve.

There's an application that processes incoming requests from a network socket.

The requests consist of multiple attribute value pairs.

I want the administrator to be able to filter the debug logging generated by processing those requests, by the attribute value pairs in the request.

The administrator would enter multiple conditions, with each condition mapping to a different output stream e.g.:

- if ((&user == 'bar') && (&host == 'foo') && (&ip = 192.168.0.1)) -> write debug to fd 9
- if ((&host == 'baz') && (&user == 'bar')) -> write debug to fd 10

Efficient evaluation of the above conditions requires that user only need be evaluated once. e.g. if (&user != 'bar') then we can stop processing.

It's obvious some sort of tree structure is needed...

I should also mention, that in the scenario i'm describing, there are no side effects from condition evaluation (you cannot perform assignment).  So operands to most of the logical operators can be re-ordered without issue.

What is the computer science concept that deals with this problem?  It has the smell of something NP complete.

Update: Follow up question. Are there any C libraries or expression languages such as BPF that could help solve the real world problem, or provide a generic implementation of the computer science concept?

Comment: Is the '==' the only comparison operator allowed? No !=, <, <=, etc?

Comment: No, standard set of comparison operators, bitwise operators, and two pattern matching operators (``=~`` and ``!~``).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this qualifies as "computer science concept", but you could tackle your issue with techniques from data flow planing / synthesis / scheduling. This is especially helpful when your operations have different costs associated (a pattern matching of a string is probably way more expensive than a bit-exact comparison of a byte).

Basically every "atomic" condition (like `user == 'bar'`) would become a node in what's (I think) called a sequence graph. Compound conditions (`&&` and probably `||` and `!`) then become further nodes in this (directed) graph, with an edge from their operands (nodes) to them.

Nodes can be given "durations", e.g. a atomic string comparison takes 20 time units, whereas an `&&` of multiple (already evaluated) conditions only takes 1 time unit.

You can then utilize different scheduling algorithms on this graph. Candidates (that I know of) are ASAP (As Soon As Possible), ALAP (As Late As Possible), "List Scheduling" and [Force Directed Scheduling](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/temp/JULY/force-directed-scheduling.pdf).

These scheduling algorithms basically compile your graph into an ordered list, specifying an ideal (or heuristically good) order in which you should evaluate the operands in order to get a result for all (complete) condition expressions. This is **not really** what you need.

The above scheduling algorithms are designed in order to produce plans when one has limited (hardware) resources (that are capable of executing the operations represented by the nodes) available, but are all concerned evaluating the full expression.

You'd need to extent this to incorporate the probability that a comparison could return a result that makes calculating further nodes pointless. I don't know how, though, so that's something you'd need to figure out yourself.

In order to do this I'd write a program that - given some complex conditions and some (preferably large) test data - finds (stochastic hill climbing, simulated annealing, genetic algorithm) a good schedule such that the mean expected time is good, and then let different (devised from above graph) scheduling algorithms compete against it.

All of the above is about static scheduling, there are also dynamic scheduling algorithms that could make use of the (step by step known) results of the atomic conditions to possibly make better plans.

Comment: That's a excellent answer! Yes, on the whiteboard i'd gotten as far as treating each atomic condition as a node, amortizing each node a based on cost of evaluation, how much of the graph could be excluded based on the result, and probablity each of the branch being executed.

The really simple and stupid way of getting probabilities would be to sample incoming packets, evaluate the complete expression DAG, and record the results.  It needn't be done in real time.

What I didn't think about was applying a scheduling algorithm to the graph to turn it into an ordered list.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is called "boolean algebra".  Boolean algebra expressions can be simplified using techniques such as [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or, in general, other [circuit minimization techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions).  This field goes back to basic digital logic (before digital computers existed) and is very well studied.

In specific cases, like searching through linear log files, you are unlikely to speed up your program because any program searching through unindexed log files is likely to be IO-bound.  Or in the case of filtering log entries, the cost of evaluating the filter is likely to be minimal compared to the cost of anything else that your application does.

Comment: Unlikely to be I/O bound, and condition evaluation could be expensive. The conditions would be applied when the request was received and parsed, in order to determine which output stream(s) its debug should be sent to.

The cost of calling out to pattern matching functions means there is some advantage in coming up with someone more efficient than O(n).

I know the simplification of the expressions could be handled by boolean algebra (Demorgan's Theorum etc..).

Karnaugh maps look useful. I guess I was hoping for something that described the entire problem (simplification+evaluation)

Comment: You say "unlikely to be I/O bound", which tells me that you haven't actually tested and are just guessing in the dark.  Any reasonable optimization here is going to be done in concert with profiling.  I would also expect to know the distribution of the input data.  Not sure what you mean by "calling out to pattern matching functions", since the code you wrote looks like bog-standard equality and inequality operations to me, could you elaborate on what pattern-matching functions you are talking about?

Comment: Async I/O in case of Network and Disk.  Memory access local to NUMA zone.  Network I/O via PF_PRING.  Comments beneath the question describe pattern matching operators.  Pattern evaluation requires a to call POSIX regexec() or libpcre.  libpcre regexes are pre-jit'd FWIW.

Comment: ...and of course it needs to be done in concert with profiling.  But you don't need sodding cachegrind to figure out that evaluating 100 odd regular expressions per request is likely to harm performance somewhat... and yes I could have mentioned all that, but it seemed extraneous to the core question.

Comment: Yes, you identified the problem here—that information was not at all extraneous to the core question.  "I need to optimize a few boolean expressions involving string equality" is a radically different question from "I need to evaluate a hundred regular expressions at high QPS".  Solutions that are appropriate at one scale are different from solutions appropriate at another scale, and the examples in the question give are quite misleading.  If you want to evaluate a hundred regexes, you may wish to see if you can compile all of them into a single DFA.  This can give a large speedup.

Comment: To put it into perspective, there are tons of questions on Stack Overflow every day about pointless micro-optimizations, and if the question had front-loaded the scale of QPS and query complexity then it would have been much easier to give you the answer you wanted.  It also helps if any clarifying comments get edited into the question body—those question edits show up while people are writing answers.

Comment: Fair enough.  It's a tradeoff between TLDR; and expressing enough of the requirements to make it useful.

I'll edit the question in future, didn't know it updated in real time.

Aggregating the expressions is very likely to give a performance improvement, but AFIK libpcre doesn't give the caller enough visibility or control to allow the caller to determine *which* subexpressions matched.

I guess in the case of the aggregated expression not matching, you can at least exclude one branch for each of the aggregated conditions.